# Каждое значение с новой строки

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Есть значение которые пишет пользователь (не могу знать заранее какое оно будет), для примера возьму три значения `123`, `з`, `о`. Мне их надо поместить в один столбец в excel файле. Но проблема том что когда пользователь вводит значения всё ставиться не в столбец а просто заменяет друг друга. Т.е сначало вводиться `123` ставится в строку под номером `0`: [image: номер 0]

Но когда вводиться второе значение а именно `з` оно ставится не в строку под номером 1 а в строку под номером 0, т.е заменяют друг друга и с третьим значением тоже самое. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Укажите как вы создаете DataFrame...

Comment: @MaxU `df = pandas.DataFrame({'Date': [mes]})`. `Mes` - это то что присылает пользователь

Comment: `mes` - это список значений или одно значение? Вопрос сформулирован непонятно - что надо записать в excel-file - один столбец или несколько?

Comment: @MaxU `mes` - это список значений который я не могу знать заранее (т.к его вводит пользователь). И все значения которые вводит пользователь надо записать в столбец. Первое значение ставиться там где надо (в самом вверху), но последующие значения он вводит не на новой строке. А на той-же что и первое значение то есть просто стирает первое значение и его место ставит второе значение.